# Calculating atomic forces from total force and torque on molecule in molecular dynamics (MD)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, computational-physics, molecular-dynamics

I guess this problem applies to any body that is composed of a small number of particles, but for the sake of simplicity and concreteness, let's consider a classical model of a molecule consisting of three atoms (e.g. H2O). In brief, I'm trying to calculate the forces on each atom (*atomic forces*, $\vec{F}_i$) from the total force ($\vec{F}_{CM}$) and torque ($\vec{\tau}$) on the respective molecule. Specifically, I'm looking for methods that would work *in a computer simulation* in the following cases:

1. The molecule is *rigid*, i.e. fixed distances between the atoms, but the molecule can rotate.
2. The molecule is *flexible*, i.e. the bond lengths are allowed to vary, but there is an "internal potential" that is a function of the bond lengths that causes forces on the atoms.

I think I should be able to find the 3*3=9 components of the atomic forces from the 3+3=6 components of the total force and torque on the molecule by solving a linear system of 9 equations. However, I can only think of 6 equations:

- The total molecular force equals the sum of the forces on the three molecules, i.e. $\vec{F}_{CM} = \vec{F}_1 + \vec{F}_2 + \vec{F}_3$ (3 equations).
- The total torque on the molecule is given by $\vec{\tau} = \vec{r}_1 \times \vec{F}_1 + \vec{r}_2 \times \vec{F}_2 + \vec{r}_3 \times \vec{F}_3$ where the $\vec{r}_i$ are the positions of the atoms (3 equations).

Apparently, I need three more constraints.

In the case of rigid molecules, the constraints are clearly that the distances between atoms in a molecule are fixed. If I was doing Lagrangian mechanics, I would just choose the generalized coordinates accordingly, or use Lagrange multipliers. **What is the preferred way to do this in a computer simulation?**
I've tried calculating the second derivative of the distance between each pair of atoms in a molecule and letting the resulting expression equal zero. That way I get three equations involving the particles' positions, velocities, and the atomic forces. This seems like a plausible approach but I'm not sure if it's correct.

I have no idea how to approach the case of flexible molecules with "internal potential".

**Additional details:**
I have a computer program that calculates an analytic potential for a certain interaction between triatomic molecules, and also the total force on the molecules using an analytic gradient of the potential. The potential is based on a multipole expansion of the electrostatic potential. The internal potential and its derivatives are also analytic.

I realize this question is probably vague, but I'm unsure which details are needed.

Comment: Might [scicomp.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Try to look up Computer Simulation of liquids by Allen and Tildesley ! There are algorithms concerned with what you're asking !!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer in both situations is that the forces cannot be determined from the torque and total force. For example, consider a hydrogen molecule and apply an equal and opposite force to each atom. This might stretch or compress the molecule if it's non-rigid, but both the torque and total force would be zero.